# why does the index page of my website bring me to the Lucee start page?

Tags: iis, lucee

I have a Windows 2012 web server running IIS. I've installed Lucee on it and everything seems to be working fine. I created a web site and set the default document to index.cfm. When I go to this site, I see the index.cfm file.

I created another web site, with basically identical settings as the first web site except with a different host name. However, when I go to the index.cfm page for this site, it brings me to the Lucee start page.

Additionally, I set the directory of the web site to be C:\sitename\www

However when I try to access any other page other than the index.cfm page, it gives me an error saying the page at C:\inetpub\www cannot be found. Its like it is looking in the wrong place. I have verified that the location of the directory for the site is C:\sitename\www

Why does this site not work, but the other one does. It seems to be a configuration issue, but both site are configured exactly the same with the exception of the host name.

Answer (score 0):

My Lucee configuration file at :

C:\lucee\lib\lucee-server\context\lucee-server.xml

had the wrong information in the  section. Once I corrected it, it started working again.

Comment: What kind of wrong information did you have? and how did you corrected it?